# Google maps API duration_in_traffic with waypoints

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I need to get the *duration_in_traffic* for 3 legs of a journey. I make a call to google directions service with an origin, 2 waypoints, and a destination. Google then returns a JSON object with one route, comprised of 3 legs as expected, but only gives duration, not *duration_in_traffic*. Without the waypoints it does return the *duration_in_traffic*. If you include the waypoints and set *stopover=false*, then it routes the journey via the waypoints, reports the *duration_in_traffic* but doesn't return the information as separate legs.

I need the separate legs as I need to calculate information for each leg (e.g. fuel usage).

I could split the work into 3 separate calls, but that means incurring 3x the cost and paying Google more for the privilege.

Is there a way of getting *duration_in_traffic* AND having the results split into legs, using just one call?

Answer (score 3):

This really makes sense, after all my investigation, it looks like we have to make 3 different calls to calculate the traffic duration for each routes. I am having the same issue.

But this could help at some point.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Edison NJ&destination=Morristown, NJ&waypoints=via:Scotch Plains, NJ|via:Basking Ridge, NJ&departure_time=now&key=YOURKEY

You have to use via: keyword in waypoints to plan your destination using specific points. This returns one leg with total duration in traffic and total miles in the route. This should help you.

This describes, when you want to go to Morristown NJ from Edison NJ, you will be going through Scotch Plains and Basking Ridge waypoints.

{
distance: {
text: "19.2 mi",
value: 30859
},
duration: {
text: "40 mins",
value: 2379
},
duration_in_traffic: {
text: "35 mins",
value: 2120
}

For more info go to
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints